# Why is Realme Android 12 auto-denying my permission requests for location and phone state?

Tags: java, android, permissions

I am developing an app for live tracking . issue i am facing is in realme android 12 when i ask for permission it is auto denying the permission

private void checkPermission() {

```
    String[] permissions = new String[0];
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        permissions = new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE};
    } else {
        permissions = new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE};
    }
    Permissions.check(this/*context*/, permissions, null/*rationale*/, null/*options*/, new PermissionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onGranted() {

                }

                @Override
                public boolean onBlocked(Context context, ArrayList<String> blockedList) {
                    gotoSettings();
                    return super.onBlocked(context, blockedList);
                }

                @Override
                public void onDenied(Context context, ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
                    super.onDenied(context, deniedPermissions);
                    checkPermission();
                }
            }

    );

}
```

i am using implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8'
dependency